# image/pjpeg and image/jpeg

Tags: php, image, browser

Do you know if I can send to browser the MIME type `image/jpeg` even if the image I am outputting is `image/Pjpeg`? Or are they different format?

Comment: Just put the content-type truthfully - browsers should be able to handle the rest...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe most browsers wouldn't mind, except Internet Explorer which treats pjpeg files differently.

According to [this conversation](https://web.archive.org/web/20110813005937/http://seewhatever.de/blog/?p=50), you should accept both image/pjpeg and image/jpeg from your clients as upload mime types, but force the image/jpeg when serving downloads.

Comment: According to [this explanation](http://www.evolve.co.nz/how-to-fix-a-pjpeg-image-upload-error) I would rather ask users to either use a standards-complying browser or manipulate their images so that even IE will comply to [IANA standards](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/index.html).

Comment: Poor! This conversation is not a reference

Comment: The information linked in the answer is not available anymore. The shown page seems a _buy this domain_ placeholder where I can just read: _The Sponsored Listings displayed above are served automatically by a third party. Neither the service provider nor the domain owner maintain any relationship with the advertisers. In case of trademark issues please contact the domain owner directly (contact information can be found in whois)._