# PHP Header - Content-type: image/jpeg - Not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: php, header, file-get-contents

We all hate Internet Explorer when building HTML templates, or modifying websites. Well I recently built a PHP image script to hide the location of the URL. It works fine for Firefox, Chrome and even Safari.

Internet Explorer refuses to display the image from the PHP script. It does not even give the broken image icons. Simply blank squares.

Android also has the same issue, but I can get to that another time and might be related.

Here is my code for the image script:

```
$image_id = $_GET['id'];

include "mysql_connect.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE code='$image_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$r=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$imagepath=$r['path'];

// Produce proper Image
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo file_get_contents("$imagepath");
```

I searched high and low on Google and this website. Could not find a solid source explaining why Internet Explorer is not displaying the image.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the ***raw*** output of this script? Does it look identical to the JPEG data on disk? No trailing or preceding output?

Comment: For Firefox, it displays the image. Internet Explorer shows ASCII code it appears. I've also tried using include($imagepath);

Comment: Either you are outputting whitespace before or after the image data, or you are missing a content-length header. You also have and SQL injection problem with this script.

Comment: Can you link the webpage? I wanna test it

Comment: Sorry, cannot link. Signed an NDA and it's a porn website ;)

Comment: Found the problem... apparently Internet Explorer did not like my height attribute. Removed it, and it worked. Guess I should get my thumbnail script running, as that would of solved my problem anyways... Thanks for the help everyone.

<img width="100%" height="40%" src="image.php?id=<?php echo $img_code; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img_title; ?>" border="0" />

Answer (score 11):

The Content-Type header name is written with an uppercase T. I am not sure if that is the issue, but some browsers might not recognize the Content-Type header when it is written with a lowercase t. Thus, you should use:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

Something else that might be a problem, is when you try to display an image that is not a jpeg, but a png or gif, while you give the image/jpeg content-type header. So, you should ensure that you give the correct content-type to the browser.

Comment: Fixed the capital T. At the moment I am only testing with JPEG.

Answer (score 2):

Internet explorer uses the mime type `image/pjpeg`. You use `pjpeg` for IE and `jpeg` for other browsers.

```
header("Content-Type: image/pjpeg");
```

Source: [image/pjpeg and image/jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147049/image-pjpeg-and-image-jpeg)

Comment: Internet Explorer needs image/pjpeg as content-type only for progressive encoded jpegs

Comment: I read that somewhere, and tried it. Tried again. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Set the content length header.

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($imagepath));
```

Comment: Good suggestion, I did add that a little while ago when Datasage recommended it. There are no trailing white spaces either.

Answer (score -1):

I think I know what the problem is.

Internet Explorer expects you to use image/jpeg and not image/jpg.

Try this:

```
Header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

All browsers accept this format, and you won't have to worry anymore.

Comment: This worked for me. I had a site where none of the JPG's displayed in Internet Explorer. It turned out that I had set the content-type to image/jpg. When I changed it to image/jpeg everything worked correctly.