# The image "http://localhost/loginCaptcha.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, captcha

I am trying to get a `CAPTCHA` to work. I have `PHP` files:

`loginCaptcha.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = $_SESSION['secure'];
$font_size = 30;

$image_width = 200;
$image_height = 40;

$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font.ttf', $text);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

`starter.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000,9999);
?>

<img src="loginCaptcha.php" />
```

When I run `loginCaptcha.php` the error comes from the title. When I run `starter.php` I get what looks like an undefined image. I checked and I have "gd" installed. I am using `xampp` so it came with it but I double checked anyway.

I read other solutions but they did not really help me.

Thanks.

Comment: open `loginCaptch.php` directly and view source...

Comment: It's been a looong time since I messed with image manipulation in PHP. Is font.ttf available/accessible?

Comment: `<img source="loginCaptch.php"/>`: `.php` isn't an image source

Comment: Always check isset ($_SESSION['secure']) before assigning it to any variable, BTW :)

Comment: @DLJ, loginCaptcha.php is reporting image/jpg as the content type, so the browser should render it as a JPEG image. The file extension is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, just checked and then found out it was possible

Comment: Try to erase every line, and leave only imagecreate, and imagejpeg and header line. Check if it works. If yes, uncomment line by line, and you will see where the problem is ;).

Comment: I have tried with "if (!isset($_POST['secure'])) {
 $_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000,9999);
} else {
 if ($_SESSION['secure'] == $_POST['secure']) {
  echo 'A match';
 } else {
  echo 'Incorrect, try again';
  $_SESSION['secure'] = rand(1000,9999);
 }
}" too and I have the same problem.

Comment: @Jacek, I tried that and I have the same problem. It is frustrating because I basically followed each and single step from this 4 video tutorial... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yt2iE2-jYoI

Comment: Could it be because it saves mine in UTF-8 encoding instead of ANSI ?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably something wrong with your PHP code or something is bugging.

You could try removing the content-type header and see what your PHP outputs, there will most likely be a notice, error or warning which prevents your browser from reading a binary request because it contains ascii text

Comment: thanks answer worked great, i had undefined notice, after fixing it i got my captcha, :)

Answer (score 1):

try after installing **php gd**

```
# apt-get install php5-gd
```

or

```
# sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

you must restart the web service after installing **php-gd**.

Answer (score 0):

OK. the only thing, that comes into my mind is to check absolutely minimal working example. So try to make a file called for examle image.php, and write there:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $image_width = 200;
    $image_height = 40;
    $image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
    imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

And check if it is working (localhost/image.php or something like that). The browser should display something that is image. **Be 100% sure, that Content-Type (Type) is from capital 'T'.** Some browsers had problems with that ([PHP Header - Content-type: image/jpeg - Not working for Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148586/php-header-content-type-image-jpeg-not-working-for-internet-explorer)).

Then please write in comment what happens. If there are any problems, please remove the header line. Then php should "error" something :). Hope it helps... I will update this post due to Your answers, as there is to little that we know, to answer it just like that :).

Best regards.

Comment: I've tried this and what i get is a black rectangular black box on a grey background. When I try and pull it it looks like an image. I guess it works but I still can't figure out what's wrong with my code. And btw, it doesn't matter if it's "Content-type" or "Content-Type", both of them works the same for me.

Comment: Yeah, but internet explorer below some versions don't recognize them... And have you tried to add another lines of your code to that? one by one? What happens? :)

Comment: The following lines of code are screwing the program: `$text = $_SESSION['secure'];` and `imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font.ttf', $text);
 imagejpeg($image);` and `for($i = 1; $i <= 30; $i++) {
 $x1 = rand(1, 100);
 $y1 = rand(1, 100);
 $x2 = rand(1, 100);
 $y2 = rand(1, 100);

 imageline($image, x1, y1, x2, y2, $text_color);
  }`