# I can open picture from local, but when I visit from website there is always present contain some errors

Tags: python, django, file-io, httpresponse, image

I can locally visit my picture, but when I want my visit from my django server there is always error.

the source code:

```
  from django.http.response import HttpResponse
  import mimetypes

  fd = open(CONFIG.SERVICES_PATH + sname+'/'+url,'r')
  print CONFIG.SERVICES_PATH + sname+'/'+url
  mime_type_guess = mimetypes.guess_type(url)
  print mime_type_guess
  data = fd.read()
  fd.close()
  response = HttpResponse(data,mimetype = mime_type_guess[0])
```

the print out on console is:

```
E:/workspace/sydney/main/services/Hunt-Club/shop/1.jpg
('image/pjpeg', None)
```

I can visit the picture from local path, but when I run the django server and visit from browser it gives me errors:

http://localhost:8000/gallery/image/Hunt-Club/shop/1/” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.">

I do not know want I give correct path and read the data, there is still error for picture require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find where my error is, the read image file code should be:

```
fd = open(CONFIG.SERVICES_PATH + sname+'/'+url,'rb')
```

Because in windows open file default applying open in ASCII, so the file doesn't read properly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rethink serving files through the django app.
Instead you should serve them from /static folder which in an apache setup you would configure using an alias.

That being said, check this out: [image/pjpeg and image/jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147049/image-pjpeg-and-image-jpeg)

It says it may have something to do with serving pjpeg content-type to IE.

Hope that helps.